# How to autoclose and click icon datepicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have problem with [code](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/):

```
<div class="control-group input-append date">
  <label class="control-label" for="cid">Check In</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="span8 required" name="cid" type="text" id="cid">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the `javascript`:

```
<script>
   $('#cid').datepicker();
</script>
```

Exactly I have done insert `jquery` and `datepicker javascript`.

Problem:

1. The date can't auto close. I want to after click date, the table date will autoclose.
2. The icon calender can't click. I want to if user click icon calender beside form input, the table calender will showing.

Thanks

Comment: The thing is, `datepicker` by default *should* close upon clicking a date, is there not any JavaScript errors in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try :

```
$('.datepicker tbody').on('click', function(){  $('.datepicker').hide() });



$('.icon-calendar').on('click', function(){ $('.datepicker').toggle()   });
```

You have to precise the jquery selector in case where you have multi icon calendar or datepicker;

Comment: great, but if I add 2 field icon-calender, actually the icon can't click. Any mistake?